# Do clothing buffs stack?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

I wonder if anyone knows if the buff's from clothing stack at all? I've got a few items which are +Face Time EXP and I want to know if it's worth stacking for it to open up new items a bit quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clothing set bonuses only apply if you wear a matching set (top, bottom, feet). Accessories bonuses do stack for all 4 slots (wristband, watch, glasses, chain).

Comment: I assume also for hair. As I'm pretty certain the Retro Triad DLC has a bonus on the hair, which counts as a hat! So you can have hat hair ;)

Comment: I never knew Asian mafia was into wigs!